# Highcharts: Highmaps - Choropleth maps - All states are the same color

Tags: json, highcharts, asp.net-mvc-5, highmaps

I have copied the demo code for the United States color axis map from the Highcharts website and substituted my own JSon file of values.  The values are showing up in the tooltip and the legend has color gradients and values, but the states are all one medium blue color.  The file values range from a few hundred to almost $4 million dollars for the states.  This html page is being called in MVC5.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/us/us-all.js"></script>
    <script>


    $(function () {
    $.getJSON('/HighChart/GetStates', function (data) {
    // Make codes uppercase to match the map data
    $.each(data, function () {
    this.State = this.State.toUpperCase();
    });

    // Instanciate the map
    $('#container').highcharts('Map', {

    chart : {
    borderWidth : 1
    },

    title : {
    text : 'Sales per State'
    },

    legend: {
    layout: 'horizontal',
    borderWidth: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.85)',
    floating: true,
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 25
    },

    mapNavigation: {
    enabled: true
    },

    colorAxis: {
        min: 1,
        max: 5000000,
    type: 'logarithmic',
    minColor: '#EEEEFF',
    maxColor: '#000022',
    stops: [
    [0, '#EFEFFF'],
    [.67, '#4444FF'],
    [1, '#000022']
    ]
    },

    series : [{
    animation: {
    duration: 1000
    },
    data : data,
    mapData: Highcharts.maps['countries/us/us-all'],
    joinBy: ['postal-code', 'State'],
    dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    color: '#FFFFFF',
    format: '{point.State}'
     },
    name: 'Total Sales',
    tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{point.State}: {point.TotalSales}'
    }
    }]
    });
    });
    });
    </script>
    <title>Map</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    <p>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="history.go(-1);">Return</a>

    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

My Json file is as follows:

```
[
{"Year":2015,"State":"","TotalQuantity":1318,"TotalSales":0.0000,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"AK","TotalQuantity":19,"TotalSales":4745.6900,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"AL","TotalQuantity":148,"TotalSales":38313.9300,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"AR","TotalQuantity":11,"TotalSales":1610.9500,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"AZ","TotalQuantity":154,"TotalSales":42988.8000,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"CA","TotalQuantity":3640,"TotalSales":1634505.3344,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"CO","TotalQuantity":6200,"TotalSales":3863600.7213,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"CT","TotalQuantity":2240,"TotalSales":400435.9686,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"DE","TotalQuantity":4328,"TotalSales":1236465.4315,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"FL","TotalQuantity":3689,"TotalSales":674759.7803,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"GA","TotalQuantity":3182,"TotalSales":795062.7901,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"HI","TotalQuantity":17,"TotalSales":21887.0000,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"IA","TotalQuantity":227,"TotalSales":58511.3800,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"ID","TotalQuantity":199,"TotalSales":64104.1200,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"IL","TotalQuantity":1356,"TotalSales":481361.1978,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"IN","TotalQuantity":2027,"TotalSales":532739.3100,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"KS","TotalQuantity":940,"TotalSales":216844.0900,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"KY","TotalQuantity":511,"TotalSales":136370.9100,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"LA","TotalQuantity":35,"TotalSales":9926.0500,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"MA","TotalQuantity":4638,"TotalSales":2262278.2147,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"MD","TotalQuantity":4116,"TotalSales":1119331.7664,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"ME","TotalQuantity":1725,"TotalSales":256750.5322,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"MI","TotalQuantity":2837,"TotalSales":785167.4863,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"MN","TotalQuantity":19396,"TotalSales":6560988.9155,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"MO","TotalQuantity":239,"TotalSales":45533.1359,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"MS","TotalQuantity":4,"TotalSales":920.8000,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"MT","TotalQuantity":41,"TotalSales":14209.1000,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"NC","TotalQuantity":5506,"TotalSales":1679007.6369,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"ND","TotalQuantity":5,"TotalSales":883.0000,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"NE","TotalQuantity":49,"TotalSales":12603.4600,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"NH","TotalQuantity":2661,"TotalSales":656975.7190,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"NJ","TotalQuantity":4899,"TotalSales":1857249.7522,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"NM","TotalQuantity":18,"TotalSales":847.1700,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"NV","TotalQuantity":2,"TotalSales":75.0000,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"NY","TotalQuantity":805,"TotalSales":295242.2600,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"OH","TotalQuantity":1712,"TotalSales":533413.1700,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"OR","TotalQuantity":3377,"TotalSales":1164709.0624,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"PA","TotalQuantity":2292,"TotalSales":601890.9000,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"PR","TotalQuantity":2,"TotalSales":115.5000,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"SC","TotalQuantity":2453,"TotalSales":1059821.3817,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"SD","TotalQuantity":250,"TotalSales":84275.1400,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"TN","TotalQuantity":2056,"TotalSales":609389.7013,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"TX","TotalQuantity":1917,"TotalSales":710662.2750,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"UT","TotalQuantity":6416,"TotalSales":1154119.6931,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"VA","TotalQuantity":3021,"TotalSales":479353.2296,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"VT","TotalQuantity":402,"TotalSales":129859.0000,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"WA","TotalQuantity":842,"TotalSales":238343.3901,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"WI","TotalQuantity":12861,"TotalSales":3228575.1303,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"WV","TotalQuantity":1651,"TotalSales":291851.3200,"IsDistributor":0},
{"Year":2015,"State":"WY","TotalQuantity":72,"TotalSales":29821.2600,"IsDistributor":0}]
```

Comment: Where is `value` property in your JSON? Your tooltip works, because you changed it's format, but you didn't set any values (in Highcharts terms) for points. Try this: `data: data.map(function(el) { el.value = el.TotalSales; return el;});`

Comment: Thank you!  That was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value` property in your JSON is not set. Your tooltip works, because you changed it's format, but you didn't set any values (in Highcharts terms) for points. Try this:

```
data: data.map(function(el) { 
  el.value = el.TotalSales; 
  return el;
});
```