# Highmaps choropleth showing unique color/ Highmap not seeing the value field in the data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have been trying to build a world choropleth maps with Highcjart but all areas in my map are appearing the same color even though the range's are different. The values are showing up in the tooltip.
I took inspiration from the example  here :

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.11.0/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/mapdata/custom/world-continents
I have noticed that in my `tooltip` Highmap is not reading the `point.region`, or `point.value` nor the `point.name`
I look all around to different problems people are facing with this on Stackoverflow suc ah these:

[Highcharts: Highmaps - Choropleth maps - All states are the same color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186586/highcharts-highmaps-choropleth-maps-all-states-are-the-same-color)
[Highmaps - Choropleth maps - All area are the same color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40966194/highmaps-choropleth-maps-all-area-are-the-same-color)

but that didn't seem to fix my problem.

```
 let rendermap = Highcharts.mapChart("map-container", {
  chart: {
    map: "custom/world",
    backgroundColor: "#EEF0EF",
     spacing: [1, 0, 0, 1],
  },
  title: {
    text: "",
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  borderColor: "#EEF0EF",
  mapNavigation: {
    enabled: true,
    enableDoubleClickZoomTo: true,
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  mapNavigation: {
    enabled: true,
    buttonOptions: {
      theme: {
        fill: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)",
        "stroke-width": 1,
        stroke: "#fb9718",
        r: 13,
        states: {
          hover: {
            fill: "#fb9718",
          },
          select: {
            stroke: "#039",
            fill: "#fb9718",
          },
        },
      },
      verticalAlign: "top",
      alignValue: "center",
    },
  },
  tooltip: {
   borderWidth: 0,
   shadow: false,
   useHTML: true,
   footerFormat:
    '<span style="font-size: .750em;color:gray;">{point.region}</span>',
   padding: 0,
   headerFormat: '<b style="font-size:1.50em">{point.key}</b><br/>',
   pointFormat: '<span style="font-size:1em">{point.risk}</span>',
   style: {
    width: "500px",
   },
},
   colorAxis: {
    min: 0
    },
    series: [
      {
        data: newmapdata,
        mapData: Highcharts.maps["custom/world"],
        type: "map",
        joinBy: ["iso-a2", "code2"],
        states: {
          hover: {
            color: "#F4edba",
          },
        },
      },
    ],

    // colors: ["#CBCDCC"],
    legend: {
      enabled: false,
    },
});
```

Then I update the data in my map this way.

```
rendermap.update({
  series: [
      {
        data: newmapdata,
        mapData: Highcharts.maps["custom/world"],
        type: "map",
        joinBy: ["iso-a2", "code2"],
        states: {
          hover: {
            color: "#F4edba",
          },
        },
      },
    ]});
```

My data is:

```
let newmapdata=[
  {
    name: "infrastructure",
    value: 0,
    region: "EUROPE",
    code: "Albania",
    code3: "ALB",
  },
  {
    name: "infrastructure",
    value: 11.9,
    region: "EUROPE",
    code: "Austria",
    code3: "AUT",
  },
  {
    name: "infrastructure",
    value: 2,
    region: "EUROPE",
    code: "Belgium",
    code3: "BEL",
  },
  {
    name: "infrastructure",
    value: 16.5,
    region: "EUROPE",
    code: "Bulgaria",
    code3: "BGR",
  },
  {
    name: "infrastructure",
    value: 12.2,
    region: "EUROPE",
    code: "Croatia",
    code3: "HRV",
  },
  {
    name: "infrastructure",
    value: 14.1,
    region: "EUROPE",
    code: "Cyprus",
    code3: "CYP",
  },
  {
    name: "infrastructure",
    value: 5.9,
    region: "EUROPE",
    code: "Denmark",
    code3: "DNK",
  },
  {
    name: "infrastructure",
    value: 15.2,
    region: "EUROPE",
    code: "Estonia",
    code3: "EST",
  },
  {
    name: "infrastructure",
    value: 4.2,
    region: "EUROPE",
    code: "Finland",
    code3: "FIN",
  },
  {
    name: "infrastructure",
    value: 4.3,
    region: "EUROPE",
    code: "France",
    code3: "FRA",
  },
  {
    name: "infrastructure",
    value: 19.1,
    region: "EUROPE",
    code: "Germany",
    code3: "DEU",
  },
  {
    name: "infrastructure",
    value: 8.5,
    region: "EUROPE",
    code: "Greece",
    code3: "GRC",
  },
  {
    name: "infrastructure",
    value: 8.1,
    region: "EUROPE",
    code: "Hungary",
    code3: "HUN",
  },
  {
    name: "infrastructure",
    value: 21,
    region: "EUROPE",
    code: "Iceland",
    code3: "ISL",
  },
  {
    name: "infrastructure",
    value: 37.5,
    region: "EUROPE",
    code: "Ireland",
    code3: "IRL",
  },
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correctly connect your data to the mapdata:

```
    series: [{
        joinBy: ["iso-a3", "code3"],
        ...
    }],
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9z2jyo43/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.map.joinBy